# Can and cannot load related query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm pulling my hair right now, I cannot figure out what the problem is.

This is my setup:

The **Score** model **hasMany** **tags** through a query that looks like this:

```
class Score extends Model
{
    .....
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ScoreTag', 'score_id')
         ->leftJoin('tags', 'score_tags.tag_id', '=', 'tags.tag_id')
         ->select('tags.*');          
    } 
}
```

I am using the https://github.com/esbenp/bruno package for loading relation through the API url. When calling this from the client using  http://mockupurl/scores?includes[]=tags
everything works fine, the tags is included and retrieved together with the scores. But when I am trying to use...

```
Score::with('tags')->get();
```

...in the backend, the tags are not being fetched. I have a similar setup in another project that works fine.

the results is shown with no tags like below:

```
"tags": []
```

I am currently using laravel 5.4 and wonder if there is something I am missing in order to load the related query?

Comment: Why does your relationship query only select `tags` columns when you use `App\ScoreTag` as the target model? Shouldn't it be `$this->hasMany('App\Tag', ...`?

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your query it looks like you want to select all the Tag models that a Score model has through the ScoreTag model. Doing the join and custom select inside your relationship definition is not going to work like that.

You may be better off trying the [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship to achieve this functionality.

```
function tags()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Tag::class, ScoreTag::class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it is working, when using the Bruno package...thats why im a bit confused. The hasmanythrough did not work when i tried it before. Will try it again

Comment: Weird, the tags are actually fetched, but the are not shown in the results when using postman. But when i call Score::find(1)->tags they are actually there